# Synonym for factotum

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for the word "factotum" ("a man  who do everything").

Is "handyman" a good synonym for someone who is able of doing  manual work in different domains (electricity, construction...) ? In particular, does this word have any connotation ? I search a neutral word.

Is "factotum" a well-known word ? In fact, we have the same word in French but most of the people doesn't know/understand it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/factotum

Comment: FWIW, "factotum" is a rarely used word in the US.

Comment: 'handyman' means someone who can fix many small mechanical/carpentry things around the house. A 'factotum' is someone who can take care of many small errands/handles small situations. One is not the other.

Comment: What did a thesaurus tell you?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for a [**jack-of-all-trades**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jack-of-all-trades):

> a person who can do passable work at various tasks : a handy versatile person

It *is* however used in the expression *jack of all trades, master of none*, referring to someone with a very diverse skill set, who nonetheless is not really very good at any particular task.

Comment: Most dictionaries, and thesauri will give things like "handyman", "jack-of-all-trades" etc as synonymous. However "handyman" is usually applied to a person who does minor repair work etc, whether it be carpentry, electrical, mechanical, building etc. on a jobbing basis. In my experience "factotum" is used more to describe someone who works exclusively for the same boss, on a wide range of general duties of an administrative nature.

Comment: Consider “dogsbody” as a less formal alternative along the same lines